# Partial files using default http client on android

Tags: android, wcf, http, get

```
String  ExecuteGetFileCommand(String url,String [] params) {


    try {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 30000;
int timeoutSocket = timeoutConnection*2;
       String  ap = null;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection*80);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket*80);




     HttpGet getrequest = new HttpGet(url);


    DefaultHttpClient getclient = new  DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

   HttpResponse respo= getclient.execute(getrequest);

   if ( respo.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200 )
   {
       return null;
   }
    HttpEntity ent=respo.getEntity();

 //   Log.i(Tools.TAG,filename);
    InputStream content = ent.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
    }





    ap=builder.toString();







        return ap;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Tools.Errorhandling(ex);
        return null;


    }


}
```

Hi i created a wcf service whitch sends files in xml format , which are usualy around 140kb  when i test the service using the restclient extension on firefox the file comes complete but when i  test it with the android library it comes only partially .
the code above is from the method that gets the file . any idea ? i used every http libary i could found on the net and done nothing ..

Comment: How partial is partial? How many lines from how many? Reproducable?

Comment: Don't know how many lines I just know how the file ends